# Progress Bar по условию

Tags: python, progress-bar

Подскажите как правильно реализовать прогресс бар на основа модуля progress, который будет работать синхронно со всем кодом. Прочитал много статей , везде в примере указывают:

```
for i in range(***):
```

Но , как быть если «например»:

1. Имеем тхт файл с текстовыми строками
2. далее нужно получить строки и что-либо проделать с ними (неважно что)
   Как заставить прогресс бар двигаться синхронно с каждой итерацией проделанной над каждой строкой из тхт

Может есть какие-то автоматические модули, которые при старте кода, запускают прогресс бар , а когда код заканчивается , то и прогресс бар завершается одновременно с кодом.

Answer (score 1):

Прогресс бар работает при условии, что известно число итераций. Иначе от чего считать прогресс? По такому принципу работают tqdm и rich.

Если количество строк в файле заранее не известно (а это наверняка так), можно за конечное значение взять размер файла. А переменная итерации на каждом цикле чтения строки будет увеличиваться не на единицу, а на размер считанной строки. rich точно это умеет. Только нужно учесть, что если файл текстовый в кодировке utf-8, то вычислять размер строки нужно в занимаемых байтах, а не символах.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте лучше модуль `tqdm`, примерно так:

```py
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in tqdm(f.readlines()):
        # здесь что-то делаете со строками
```

Просто оборачиваете в него любую коллекцию по которой вы итерируетесь через `for`. К сожалению, нет большого смысла итерироваться по генератору, например, просто по файлу `f` без `readlines`, потому что генератор не сообщает, какая у него длина, и прогресс-бар в этом случае бесполезен.